# make an image bigger on hover and show php variable below

Tags: php, html, css, image

I have a php file, where I had made some querys to a phpbb database, obtaining some variables (like  topic_title and a image link)

I know how to show the image in php, but now I want to make them bigger on hover, and, when the image is big, show the topic title below, is this posible?

here is the code:

```
  echo '<table cellspan="4">';
      echo "<tr>\n";
      while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
          preg_match('/\[r?img:(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/r?img:(.*?)\]/', $fila['post_text'], $fila_contenido);
          $sololink = preg_replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9_+.-]','',@$fila_contenido[2]);
          $fila2 = $fila["post_subject"];
          echo "<th><img src=$sololink></th>";
       }
  echo "</tr>\n";
```

then I want to grow $sololink (the image) on hover, and show $fila2 (the title) below the grew image

thanks

Comment: You can probably get the image to grow with CSS, but you'll need JavaScript if you want the title to be visible or move.

Comment: @DaveChen showing, hiding and moving of elements can be achieved using css,  transitions and animations without the need of js.

Comment: oki... but how? i dont know how to do that effect

Comment: @t.niese Yep, I posted an answer, but it's only possible if you have a parent container (which wasn't in his original question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example only using CSS.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="image" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />
    <div class="title">Title of this image is here</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image {
    -webkit-transition: width 2s, height 2s;
    transition: width 2s, height 2s;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}

.title {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s;
    transition: opacity 2s;
    font-size: 30px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.container:hover .image {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
}

.container:hover .title {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9pCNx/)